# Sort database results by Date, Time or Rating

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

I am trying to create a sort on my database results. The user is presented with a view with a search input where they can type the title of a question and 3 buttons which will let the user sort by either date, time or reputation. I have tried searching for a way to do this but have not found anything that can help me. Is there anyway i can do this?

Below is the method i am using to retrieve the data from the database.

Model function:

```
function viewq($qtitle)
{    

$query = $this->db->where('title',$qtitle)->from('questions')->get();
return $query->result();

}
```

Controller Function:

```
  public function search()
    {
            $qtitle = $this->input->post('title');
            $data ['query'] = $this->question_model->viewq($qtitle); 
            $this->load->view('search_view', $data);

    }
```

Comment: What framework or library do you use to connect and query the database?

Answer (score 2):

You should use ORDER BY date, time or reputation.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

As you can see, you can use that if you want the most recent result first

```
$this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
```

You can change "date" for time, date or reputation and DESCending for ASCending